# svn path-based authorization

Tags: svn, directory, authorization, naming

The question is a bit stupid but I can't get it sorted. I have a server with SVN that uses the SVNPath directive in httpd.conf and all works fine with path authorizations.
Now I'm installing a second server where I'm going to use SVNParentPath directive and I've got it all running except I can't get the authorization part quite right. From what I understand it's the same as when you use SVNPath but you need to specificy the repo name before the folder name.
My SVNParentPath is /srv/svn/ and I created a directory /srv/svn/testproj and then ran

svnadmin create /srv/svn/testproj

Now I'm configuring my authorization file:

```
[/]
* =
svnadmin = rw
adusgi = rw


[testproj:/svn/testproj]
demada = rw
degari = rw
scarja = rw
```

Now if I try to commit /svn/testproj using user svnadmin or adusgi all is fine. If I try for example demada it doesn't work. (I've run the htpasswd2 commands for the user obviously. The directory is correct or at least that's how I use the directory with the SVNPath server that's already running. The part I think I'm getting wrong is the repo name. I've just used the directory name but what am I really supposed to put there?

Comment: I just realized a website called serverfault.com exists where I think my question is more apropriate. You can close it.
Thank you James
link to question on serverfault if anyone can help:
http://serverfault.com/questions/520516/svnparentpath-directory-authorization